# Tools to test SSL performance

Tags: linux, ssl, performance-testing

I'm trying to implement a TLS server with a custom engine (my server has a hardware accelerator).
I want to test the performance of my server w/ wo the engine such as number of handshake per second, number of connection...
I found a lot of online website to test SSL server but couldn't find anything to do that locally (since I can't bring the server online yet).
Is there any tools/ software to achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because its asking for a software or program recommendation. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Best way to stress test a website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/340564/608639), [how to stress test a server](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+stress+test+a+server), [ab stress test](https://www.google.com/search?q=ab+stress+test), etc

Answer (score 0):

To check the performance of the engine itself, openssl can help :
openssl -c to see all installed engines
openssl speed -engine engineid to get some performance testing for one engine

To check your server itself, I'm scared you need to script around openssl s_client